# Test Multiple fragments with one Android activity using Appium

Tags: android, testing, appium, android-testing

I have an app with one activity and multiple fragments. Is there any way I can test those Fragments with Appium? or any other automation framework?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't figured out jet how to test fragments with Appium.
Try Robotium for Android apps. It is simple to use and you can also set it up with Android Studios.
Here is the link to Robotium: 
https://code.google.com/p/robotium/
Under Wiki take an closer look at RobotiumTutorials.

In Appium you have to manage all used elements via findElement()!
So you actually don't need to call any FragmentManager.
For Android it's possible to use the method currentActivity()
but there is nothing like a FragmentManager.
Take a look at Appium API Reference: http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.2.0/?java#appium-client-libraries